# Azure Databricks UI Definition

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm curious to know what the **uiDefinitionUri** in the [Databricks ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.Databricks/2018-04-01/workspaces) is used for and what kind of file should be provided. I can see that a string is the input type and that the value is *"The blob URI where the UI definition file is located."*, however that is not very descriptive and doesn't provide any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following REST API, to get the uiDefinitionUri for Azure Databricks.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces?api-version=2018-04-01
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "name": "myWorkspace1",
      "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/myWorkspace1",
      "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces",
      "location": "East US 2",
      "tags": null,
      "sku": {
        "name": "skuName"
      },
      "properties": {
        "managedResourceGroupId": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/myManagedRG",
        "parameters": null,
        "provisioningState": "Created",
        "uiDefinitionUri": "https://path/to/workspaceCreateUiDefinition.json"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "myWorkspace2",
      "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/myWorkspace2",
      "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces",
      "location": "East US 2",
      "tags": null,
      "sku": {
        "name": "skuName"
      },
      "properties": {
        "managedResourceGroupId": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/myManagedRG",
        "parameters": null,
        "provisioningState": "Created",
        "uiDefinitionUri": "https://path/to/workspaceCreateUiDefinition.json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For more details, refer "[Workspaces -List By Resource Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/databricks/workspaces/listbyresourcegroup)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However to me this doesn't tell me what kind of information there should be in "https://path/to/workspaceCreateUiDefinition.json"